# EntityManager persist() with @Transactional does not throw DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot

We have EntityManager persist() with @Transactional. If data is being inserted with more than column length, persist does not throw DataIntegrityViolationException. It is thrown when 2-level up parent method with @Transactional returns.

```java
class Worker {

    @Transactional
    public Integer createEmployee(String name) { 
        // employeeId is generated after checking if employee exists or not
        saveEmployee(name, employeeId);
        send_to_third_party(employeeId);
        return employeeId;
    }

    saveEmployee(String name, Integer employeeId){
        Employee em = new Employee();
        // Get other data for employee like department etc.
        dao.persist(employee);
    }
}

class Dao {
    @autowired
    EntityManager em;

    @Transational
    public void persist(Object object) {
        try{
            em.persist(object);
            log("successful");
        }
        catch(RuntimeException ex) {
            log("persist failed");
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

As shown in the code, saveEmployee returns successful even if it has error like data length is more than column length. The employeeId is sent to the third party and processed. When createEmployee returns employeeId, it throws an exception 'DataIntegrityViolationException' and shows message 'String or binary data would be truncated'. In the end, employee is not saved in our DB while is processed by third party which creates mismatch and further errors in the system.

Doesn't @Transactional in the dao.persist() commit the persist operation? Why does it take so long to throw the exception?

Thank you for the help.

P.S. - We are definitely going to check for data length.

Answer (score 2):

`persist()` will only make the object managed and persistent, it will not actually do anything to the database until the transaction context is closed. To force immediate synchronisation with the database, call `flush()` after the `persist()`. This will cause the exception to be thrown immediately.

Comment: Personally, I would also call the third party only after the transactional method succeeds.

Comment: Doesn't `persist()` have its own transaction context? Won't it be closed after `persist()` and database object flushed?

Comment: @Strelok, it's rarely that simple. What is you want to rollback local changed if the remote call errors out?

Comment: @Nets you're confusing database transaction and hibernate's transaction context (opened/closed when you enter/exit the first method with @Transactional).

Comment: @Captain, yes, I am confused. Both are org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional. How do they have different type of transactional contexts? Do you mean `flush()` happens after hibernate transaction is closed which in this case is `saveEmployee()`? If it didn't have `@Transactional`, would `persist()` flush to database?